# Expansion in makefiles

Tags: makefile, expand

In the context of makefiles I often see in documentation/forums the term expansion thrown around quite a bit though it is rarely defined.  What exactly does it mean to expand a variable or parameter when talking about makefiles?

Comment: For such a simple idea, it's remarkably hard to explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a string means to replace references to variables or function calls within the string, (e.g. `$(NAME)`), with the values of those things.

Consider:

```
FOO = a b c
BAR = $(FOO) d e
BAZ = $(BAR) f g
```

The value of `BAZ` is `$(BAR) f g`. If you try to *use* it:

```
$(info $(BAZ))
```

then Make expands the variable, which is to say it replaces `$(BAZ)` with the value of `BAZ`:

```
$(info $(BAR) f g)
```

then `$(BAR)` with the value of `BAR`:

```
$(info $(FOO) d e f g)
```

then `$(FOO)` with the value of `FOO`:

```
$(info a b c d e f g)
```

and with nothing left to expand it executes the `info` function and prints out "a b c d e f g".

Note that some things expand variables and others don't. For example, the assignment `BAR = $(FOO) d e` does *not* expand the `$(FOO)` on the right-hand side. The other kind of assignment, `BAR := $(FOO) d e`, *does*.